# Having a single process write to two pipes in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm trying to implement a program that launches a process (call this app1) and pipes the stdout to two other apps (app2, app3 respectively). I have a functioning implementation where I fork() app1 twice and pipe the stdout for each, but I feel there's a cleaner solution.

What happens with my implementation is that app3 launches but doesn't show the stdout in the shell. Not looking for an exact answer to my problem, but a nudge in the right direction. I believe the issue is how I'm handling the file descriptors, but I'm still quite new to these functions so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
int pipepipe(char **app1, char **app1, char**app3){
   int fd[4]; 
   pipe(fd);
   pipe(fd+2);
   pid_t pid1 = fork();
   if(pid1 < 0){
      return 2;
   }
   if (pid1 == 0){ 
      dup2(fd[1], 1);
      dup2(fd[3], 1);
      for(int i = 0; i <4; i++){
         close(fd[i]);
      }
      execvp(app1[0], app1); 
   }

   int pid2 = fork();
   if(pid2 <0){
      return 2; 
   }
   if(pid2 == 0){ 
      dup2(fd[0], 0); 
      for(int i = 0; i <4; i++){
         close(fd[i]);
      }
      execvp(app2[0], app2);
   } 

   int pid3 = fork();
   if(pid3 < 0){
      return 2;
   }
   if(pid3 == 0){
      dup2(fd[2], 0);
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
         close(fd[i]);
      }
      execvp(app3[0], app3);
   }
   
   waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
   waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
   waitpid(pid3, NULL, 0);

   for(int i = 0; i <4; i++){
      close(fd[i]);
      }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: After each `execvp()`, add code to exit with an error condition (and probably an error message too).  There's no need to test the return value: if `execvp()` succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.

Comment: The consecutive calls `dup2(fd[1], 1); dup2(fd[3], 1);` in the `app1` child code are wrong.  Individually, they're fine, but the second closes the `fd[1]` that was duplicated to `STDOUT_FILENO` (aka `1`).  You have to use to separate file descriptors to write to the two pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consecutive calls:

```
dup2(fd[1], 1);
dup2(fd[3], 1);
```

in the `app1` child code are wrong.  Individually, they're fine, but the second call closes the `fd[1]` that was duplicated to `STDOUT_FILENO` (aka `1`).  You have to use two separate file descriptors to write to the two pipes.  So, rather than `app1` writing to its standard output, you'll probably want to think about passing (string) arguments which tell it which file descriptors to write on.  All command arguments are strings, so maybe:

```
char out1[6];
char out2[6];
sprintf(out1, "-o%d", fd[1]);
sprintf(out2, "-o%d", fd[3]);
```

and then add `out1` and `out2` to the arguments in the `app1` array.  You'd not close either `fd[1]` or `fd[3]`; you would still close `fd[0]` and `fd[2]`.

If you need to differentiate between the two apps (if `app1` writes different data to `app2` and `app3`), then you use different option letters (maybe `-o` and `-O`?) to identify which is which.

Obviously, you need appropriate argument parsing code in `app1` so it knows what to do.

The alternative is designate that file descriptor 3 will be the output to `app2` and file descriptor 4 will be the output to `app3` (leaving the standard I/O descriptors unchanged):

```
dup2(fd[1], 3);
dup2(fd[2], 4);
```

You just have to be a bit careful that you don't close either 3 or 4 in the loop over the 4 file descriptors.  The chances are that you have the following numbers:

```
fd[0] = 3
fd[1] = 4
fd[2] = 5
fd[3] = 6
```

in which case, the two dup calls would be fine, but the close loop would need to avoid closing `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` (because those values are 3 and 4).

On the whole, I prefer the explicit options, but YMMV.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed solution! I'll mark this as the answer.

But just for clarification, when you mention to avoid closing fd[0] and fd[1] do you mean in the loops I have in each process?

Comment: In the `app2` and `app3` processes, you should be fine closing all four elements of `fd` after you've duplicated the read end of the correct pipe to standard input.  It's only in the `app1` process that you have to be careful about not closing the pipes you want it to use to write to `app2` and `app3`.  The `app1` process will close the read ends of the pipes, of course.  (In each case, the `appN` process refers to the child that will execute `appN`, but the plumbing has to be complete before you execute `appN`.)